# Discord.py auto delete bot commands

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How can I automatically keep deleting someone's msg by their User ID with a bot?

Comment: Can you show what have you done so far? Are you using Cogs?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [on_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.on_message) event:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.author.id == some_id:
        await message.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `discord.ext` that's the solution:

```
@bot.event()
async def on_message(ctx):
    if message.author.id == 982628765833: #Replace the id with the person's id that you want to delete their message
        await ctx.delete()
```

Comment: Keep saying it doesn't have coro on event().

Comment: You'll need to install `discord.ext` to do this.

Comment: Check out https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/index.html. 

You should install like this:

import discord
from discord.ext import bot

After that you can only use the `@bot.event`!